# Problem formatting a subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, subscripts, kerning

```
$\nu_{\rm FWHM}$
```

prints FWHM too large.  But when I try:

```
$\nu_{\mbox{\tiny FWHM}}$
```

the size is okay but the kerning looks wrong.

What is the best way to make a compact little FWHM subscript tag on my variables?

**Solution:**

```
$\nu_{\textsc{\tiny fwhm}}$

\newcommand{\FWHM}{{\textsc{\tiny fwhm}}}
$\nu_\FWHM$
```

Comment: Try `\scriptstyle` instead of tiny.

Comment: `$\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle\rm FWHM}$` will give you the second one. Then you can squeeze them with negative space `$\nu_{\scriptscriptstyle\rm F\!W\!H\!M}$`

Comment: `\scriptstyle` actually resulted in larger text than `\tiny`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will overlap with Mico's answer, but there are couple of extra points that I'd like to make.

Loading `amsmath` has the nice feature that text font changing commands may be used in mathematics and the text resizes appropriately in subscripts etc.  The commands `\textrm`, `\textit` etc. may be used directly without having to invoke an additional `\text` command.  Often these direct commands are to be preferred over `\text`, because the latter inherits the font characterisitics from the surounding text.  My standard solution for such situation is to define a macro and use the `\textnormal` command to avoid this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\FHWM}{\textnormal{FHWM}}

\begin{document}

\( B_\FHWM \) vs. \( B_{\text{FHWM}} \) and
\( X_{B_\FHWM} \) vs. \( X_{B_{\text{FHWM}}} \)

\begin{theorem}
 Preferring \( B_\FHWM \) to  \( B_{\text{FHWM}} \)
\end{theorem}

\textbf{\( B_\FHWM \) vs. \( B_{\text{FHWM}} \)}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

An alternative to `\textnormal` is `\textup`, which will produce upright inside italic and slanted text, but will turn bold inside bold text.

However, in your case you are putting the subscript on a small symbol `\nu` and the above looks too big.  The small caps shape from `\textsc` is often designed to give the best spacing for such combinations and is a standard choice for acronyms.  You need to remember to write `\textsc{fwhm}` instead of `\textsc{FWHM}` as the latter usually produces capitals of the same size as `\textrm` capitals.  One thing to be aware of is that the standard fonts have no bold variant of `\textsc`, so I suggest you additionally use `\textnormal` to avoid surprises.  Your request for a very small font is provided by the `\tiny` command.  (My personal preference would be to omit that or to use a command from the `relsize` package.)  Below is an example with `\tiny` included.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\FHWM}{\textnormal{\tiny \textsc{fhwm}}}

\begin{document}

\( \nu_\FHWM \) vs. \( \nu_{\textsc{fhwm}} \) vs. \( \nu_{\text{FHWM}} \) 
and
\( X_{\nu_\FHWM} \) vs. \( X_{\nu_{\textsc{fhwm}}} \) vs. \( X_{\nu_{\text{FHWM}}} \)

\begin{theorem}
 Preferring \( \nu_\FHWM \) to  \( \nu_{\text{FHWM}} \)
\end{theorem}

\textbf{\( \nu_\FHWM \) vs. \( \nu_{\textsc{fhwm}} \) vs. \( \nu_{\text{FHWM}} \)}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample with textsc and tiny]

The bold cases in the above examples are there just to illustrate pitfalls.  If you really intend to use this in such contexts, then you need to think about what fonts you wish to appear and build the commands appropriately.

Comment: All I had to do was `\usepackage{amsmath}` and everything worked! Thanks!

Comment: I tried `\textsc{\tiny ...}` with both `\odot` and `\bigodot` It compiles fine with `\odot`, but I get an error message with `\bigodot`. Why is that?

Comment: @Andyc I would expect neither to work as they are math mode commands, not text.

Answer (score 14):

You may want to load the `amsmath` package to access its `\text` macro and type (in math mode, obviously):

```
\nu_{\text{FWHM}}
```

Don't use the `\rm` command in a LaTeX document.

**Addendum** -- @AndrewSwann has pointed out that FHWM, being an acronym, should be typeset in small-caps letters, i.e., as `\textsc{fhwm}`. Defining the acronym command `\FHWM` with `\newcommand\FHWM{\textsc{fhwm}}`, the following possibilities arise for typesetting the acronym as a subscript to `\nu`:

```
$\nu_{\text{FWHM}}$ % regular caps, subscript in "scriptsize" font size

$\nu_\FHWM$         % small caps, subscript in "scriptsize" font size

$\nu_{\text{\tiny\FHWM}} $  %  small caps, subscript in "tiny" font size
```

[image]

Comment: I second the use of `amsmath`, but in this case would suggest `\( \nu_{\textsc{fwhm}} \)` with `amsmath` loaded.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: I have no idea what FHWM may stand for. If it's an acronym, it would certainly be a good idea for the OP to set up a command such as `\newcommand\FHWM{\textsc{fhwm}}` in the preamble and then to use this macro throughout the document -- including in `$\nu_{\text{\FHWM}}$`.

Comment: FWHM is acronym for Full Width Half Maximum. It is used to measure the spread of a Gaussian beam (like laser beam).

Comment: @mythealias: thanks for providing this confirmation. Since it's an acronym that is (probably) used repeatedly in your paper, it's definitely worth implementing Andrew Swann's suggestion.

Comment: @AndrewSwann `amsmath` did the trick.  `\textsc{\tiny fwhm}` Is the final solution.  Using lower case `fwhm` makes all the difference compared with `\textsc{\tiny FWHM}` or any other combination.  Post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Mico Good tip on `\newcommand`.  I have at least a dozen of these in my document for common symbols that can only be written in math mode.

Answer (score 0):

You might try scalebox.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

$M_{\scalebox{.9}{$\psi_{\text{\tiny X}}\psi_{Y}$}}$

\end{document}
```

Note the \tiny before $X$ and that it makes X slightly smaller than Y. This gives two degrees of control-ability, both in the scalebox size and in the usage of text size modifiers.