# Moving the subscript down in math mode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I have an equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\chi^2_{k-1, \alpha}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This creates:

[image]

I would like the subscript (the k-1, \alpha) to be lower, to make it *really* look like a subscript.

I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139752/change-size-and-position-of-subscript-like-double-subscript) and the tug.org article by Timothy Hall. However, I cannot get the Hall version to compile. Could anyone give an MWE of how to move the subscript lower?

Comment: A cheap trick is to add a `\vphantom` of something tall, e.g. `\chi^{2}_{\vphantom{1^{H}}k-1, \alpha}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is somewhat deceiving in terms of the placement, since `\chi` is much deeper than you average symbol/letter, like `X`. For example, compare `X^2_k` to `\chi^2_k`:

[image]

You could introduce a taller subscript which should push it down further. Here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \chi^2_{k - 1, \alpha} \quad
  \chi^2_{{\textstyle\mathstrut}k - 1, \alpha}
\]

\end{document}
```

I've introduced a larger zero-width box of maximum height in `\textstyle`.

Note that dropping the subscript (through the introduction of something larger-than-usual) would impact the line height this construction sits on. It might not be visible within a math display, but be highlight if used in a regular paragraph setting.

Comment: Yes, that's why I chose it: I am literally working with \chi, so that's why I'm encountering the issue of the subscript not really looking like a subscript! Thanks very much for this solution.